# disabling XML output for the type() function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with an external compiled API, that does some XML manipulation prior to screen rendering. I am passing data to and from the API, and I want it to break cleanly so I can see where it is broken. This means I need to be able to send it text, rather Pythons internal formatting for types.

So I need to debug what types I'm sending and recieving. type() hands back xml?, and isinstance() would require testing every possible type.

So is there an alternative that will give me the stringified type that is suitable for inline evaluation?

Example:

```
mystring = str("") 
print (type(mystr))

returns <class "str">
```

If I am passing angle brackets into a binary API, I have no idea what it is doing with the data, or whether it will render in the UI at all. It does its own string parsing based on code I don't have, or even want to know.

The only part I care about is: "str".

So I have:

```
mystr = str("")
blackbox.String(mystr)
```

Where the contents and even type of mystr are unknown. (the string value is also handed to me by a blackbox) The API is rendering nothing. Though I don't know whether the fact that it is rendering nothing is because of bad string formatting, or a bad type, or because there is a string, but it is empty. I know it is SUPPOSED to be a text string with length. But I don't know if it is. If I use isinstance I have to know what I'm testing for. Which tells me nothing if I'm getting something weird. If I use type() I am sending something weird to the rending engine. So I am screwed both ways.

What I need is:

```
blackbox.String(type(mystr))
```

where the result of type is a plain ascii type name without punctuation, so that I can reasonably assess that the black box is giving and getting a plain, untainted text string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle brackets are a representational convention of the output of `type()` rather xml as such.

The output of `type()` is an object, so you can access it's `__name__` attribute to get the name of the type.

```
>>> type('')
<class 'str'>
>>> type('').__name__
'str'
```